# How to auto refresh div sensor table every 30 seconds?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am currently doing on a school project where I am using Arduino and Raspberry Pi. I managed to send the temperature sensor readings from Raspberry Pi to IoT gateway and it is updated to Mysql database. I can display the sensor table using AJAX in IoT gateway. However, the problem is that the sensorInfo table doesn't refresh itself every 30 seconds.

This is what my SensorInfo table is like

**sensorInfo table**

> Serial No | SensorID | Temp | SensorDate

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>IOT Sensor gateway</title>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }


        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","sensor.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }

}

</script>



</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h2>IoT gateway Sensor Info</h2>

<form method="post">
Select Sensor No:
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  </select>
</form>
<hr>
<br>
<div id="txtHint">Sensor readings will be displayed here...</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    showUserinfo();
    });

    function showUserinfo(){
      $('#txtHint').load('sensor.php', function(){
        setInterval(showUserinfo, 30000);
      });
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**sensor.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','admin','tempSensorReading');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}

mysqli_select_db($conn,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM SensorInfo WHERE SensorID = '".$q."' order by SerialNo desc limit 5";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>SensorNo</th>
<th>SensorDate</th>
<th>Temp</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SensorID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['SensorDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Temp'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Have been stuck in this problem for long. Glad if someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just change your `showUserInfo` function to `setInterval(showUserinfo, 30000);`? There's no need to load `sensor.php` two times on the first call. I think this may fix your problem as well.

Comment: <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    showUserinfo();
    });

    function showUserinfo(){
        setInterval(showUserinfo, 30000);
    }

</script>

Comment: You mean like this as shown above?

Comment: Sorry, no. Actually, looking through your code you've got a few problems. I'll post an answer. Give me a moment.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a few things incorrectly. For one, your `jQuery.load()` function is being called every 30 seconds, but it's calling it's parent function as well, making the script call twice, and then four times, and it's getting exponentially multiplied every 30 seconds, each time that setInterval gets called. Why don't you remove all your JS and try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Define your update function.
    var showUserInfo = function(userVal) {
        $("#txtHint").load("sensor.php?q=" + userVal, function() {
            //Anything else you want to do here.
        });
    };

    //Call your update function for the first time.
    showUserInfo();

    //Set an interval to call your update function every 30 seconds.
    setInterval(function() {
        showUserInfo($("select[name='users']").val())
    }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: Oh, then for <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)"> do I have to change anything?

Comment: I am new to programming my apologies

Comment: No. That won't work. This code doesn't have anything to do with users. What is the string you append to the URL to get the correct user?

Comment: I think it's based on the sensor no '1', '2' in the select users option values. The table is filtered according to the SensorID rows from mysql database

Comment: I researched online and found these codings for AJAX

Comment: @Jtang11 I'm confused by that statement. Do you need more assistance?